# Hierarichal Grid with Angular JS 2

Tags: angular, hierarchical-data

I am trying to implement  `Hierarchical Grid` in my `Angular 2` application similar to this one http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/hierarchy

So I started out by creating two `components`. The `Parent Component` is for parent table and `Child Component` is for child table. So when click on row from parent table, the child table will load right below it (like above example).

**This is how my html looks like**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <h1>{{pageTitle}}</h1>
        <table class="table table-striped">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>User Name</td>
                    <td>Email</td>
                    <td>Billing Method</td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr class="master-row" *ngFor="#invoice of invoices; #i = index">
                    <td><button (click)="getDetail(invoice)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></button></td>
                    <td>{{invoice.username}}</td>
                    <td>{{invoice.email}}</td>
                    <td>{{invoice.billingMethod}}</td>
                </tr>

            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

But I am having two issues:

1) How to load child table on a correct location in `DOM`? The problem is when my parent table render, all of it's rows gets created using `ngFor` directive. Now when click on a row, how to load it's child table right below it? How to identify the location?

2) In order to load child table, I was thinking to use `DynamicComponentLoader` Class, but looks like the communication between `Components` won't be possible when using `DCL`.

Please suggest

Comment: You can always `nest` components.  Check this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/SKkaMguZHHMAOYmW7to9?p=preview) it should guide you

Comment: @Abdulrahman I want to load nested component when row click on parent table. And want to inject the nested component right below the clicked row. How would I identify the correct location where to put the nested component since `DCL` require the location in DOM where to load the `component`?

Comment: I don't see any good reason for using `DynamicComponentLoader` in your situation. But here is a simple [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/fiOWuEpRanG8fYo17Yun?p=preview) to show you how to reference the target element. " check the console after clicking on a row"

Comment: @Abdulrahman Thanks. I see you are using Div based structure, however I am using table based structure. I updated my question, can you please check. I want to put child table right after the clicked row in a separate row. Can you please let me know how that could be possible

Comment: I am not sure this is possible "cleanly", because `tr` has to be directly below `tbody` or `table`. But, if you want to use DCL, then you need an anchor element that will be between the `tr` and `tbody` which will mess up the table. If you want to use `*ngIf` to show the `tr` then, `tr` has to be either inside the parent `tr` or at the bottom of the table. These kind of table restrictions are the reason I prefer `div`s

Comment: @Abdulrahman Right, I agree. But would you like to see how kendo is doing, I am looking for a similar one. They load detail row right below the master row.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fulfill your requirements using the template syntax of `ngFor`

**pre 2.0.0-beta.17 syntax**:

```
<template ngFor #item [ngForOf]="items" #i="index">
    <tr>...</tr>
</template>
```

**2.0.0-beta.17 syntax**:

```
<template ngFor let-invoice [ngForOf]="invoices" let-i="index">
    <tr>...</tr>
</template>
```

[Check out this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/l4fjXdue382XbNxlGSIM?p=preview)

In your situation it will be:

```
<template ngFor let-invoice [ngForOf]="invoices" let-i="index">
    <tr class="master-row" *ngFor="#invoice of invoices; #i = index">
        <td><button (click)="getDetail(invoice)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></button></td>
        <td>{{invoice.username}}</td>
        <td>{{invoice.email}}</td>
        <td>{{invoice.billingMethod}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr *ngIf="isInvoiceOpened(i)">
        <td colspan="100">
            <child-table [details]="details"></child-table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</template>
```

The `isInvoiceOpened()` function will return true if that particular row is opened. Which means you should have an array to hold opened rows indexes, i.e.

```
_openedDetails = [];

isInvoiceOpened(i){
  return this._openedDetails.indexOf(i)>-1;
}

getDetail(i){
  let index = this._openedDetails.indexOf(i);
  if(index > -1)
    this._openedDetails.splice(index,1);
  else
    this._openedDetails.push(i);
}
```